# How can I create a "table" with an array of object in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose the mongodb document(table) 'school' is

```
{
  classes: [
    name: 'A',
    students: [
      {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 15,
        note: 9
      },
      {
        name: 'Jane Doe'
        age: 17,
        note: 8
      },
      {
        name: 'James Doe'
        age: 15,
        note: 7
      },
    ]
  ]
}
```

How can I create a Table like

```
|  class  |   age |  sumNotes
|    A    |   15  |  16
|    A    |   17  |  8
```

In other words, I would like to create a table with the mongoDB data doing a treatment.

Comment: The whole point of using MongoDB is to use NoSQL - that is, collections of documents. If you want to have tables (in a "traditional" way if I understand you correctly) you should use some SQL database.

Comment: My goal is to generate the data that I exemplified with a table, not necessarily a table.

Comment: Do you mean `"classes"` to be an array of _objects_ consisting of `"name"` and `"students"`? I.e., `"classes": [ { "name": "A", "students": [{},{}, ...] } ]`

Comment: Yes, @rickhg12hs

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that your arrays may have multiple elements and assuming you are interested in `classes.name: "A"`, here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.school.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "classes.name": "A"
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$classes"},
  {
    "$match": {
      "classes.name": "A"
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$classes.students"},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$classes.students.age",
      "class": {"$first": "$classes.name"},
      "sumNotes": {"$sum": "$classes.students.note"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "class": 1,
      "age": "$_id",
      "sumNotes": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Sample output:

```json
[
  {
    "age": 15,
    "class": "A",
    "sumNotes": 16
  },
  {
    "age": 17,
    "class": "A",
    "sumNotes": 8
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TLvkhebstXA).